# CheckOut Transparente Pag Seguro : installment value invalid

Tags: php

Tenho em minha loja OpenCart o módulo do pagseguro de checkout transparente
reparei que em raras ocasiões algum cliente não conseguia efetuar o pagamento por cartão de crédito.
Hoje um cliente veio a loja e aconteceu novamente justo quando aplico qualquer desconto ( no valor da venda e não no produto )
ele joga o seguinte erro

> installment value invalid value: 247.82

depois de alguma pesquisa vi que é provavelmente por que o erro do valor das parcelas não bate com o valor dos produtos.

Existe alguma maneira de informar ao pagseguro o desconto aplicado ou alguma forma de resolver este erro?

Comment: Como voce faz a chamada? usa a api mesmo ou fez na mao? eles recomendam usar o extraAmount com valor negativo: 
`Parâmetro HTTP:
extraAmount 

Elemento XML:
<checkout>
<extraAmount>` https://pagseguro.uol.com.br/v2/guia-de-integracao/api-de-pagamentos.html